# The method FB.api will stop working when called from http pages in X days. Please update your site to use https for Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing an app in localhost and suddenly getting this error:

> The method FB.api will stop working when called from http pages in X days.  Please update your site to use https for Facebook Login.

Will I still be able to develop in localhost when the time runs out?

Comment: that is a good question, but i would not count on it and rather use https on localhost as well.

Answer (score 3):

As per Facebook announcement:

> You will still be able to use HTTP with “localhost” addresses, but only while your app is still in development mode.

Link: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/06/08/enforce-https-facebook-login/

Comment: Well, doesnt seem to work properly. My app is in development mode and I am seeing problems when calling FB.login() from `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Using ngrok solved the issue for me. I followed this tutorial: https://www.chrisjmendez.com/2018/04/16/using-ngrok-with-facebook-oauth-login/

Comment: `enforce http` option in developer console is disable. I don't know why it is. is there any way to enable that option ?