# Ionic Native: tried calling Facebook.login, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins

[Ionic Native: tried calling Facebook.login, but Cordova is not available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EbIv.png)

i have already cordova-plugin-facebook4": "5.0.0" but when i run it to the browser it keep asking me that the cordova.js was not found and i can't login to facebook because of that, someone already encounter this issue

please help me i am depressed about this problem

the output must be i could login to facebook in browser.

Comment: Cordova plugins doesn't work on browsers.  Cordova  is the engine that helps your to use the native components available in your android/ios phones. If you are making an android app using ionic then install a simulator in your computer for testing

Comment: Tony Manuel, thanks for your answer bro. but how about if i run it in the command of "Ionic Cordova run browser" and here the result "The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages" so it means brother even in the android/ios browsers the cordova won't work in the browser environment whatever the platforms it is.

Comment: Kindly check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397463/the-method-fb-api-will-stop-working-when-called-from-http-pages-in-x-days-pleas

Comment: one last question sir Tomy is it possible if i used react js for web then i put it in the domain like m.website.com just to make it a mobile version in web is it possible sir without using a ionic technology.

Comment: You should understand the difference between a mobile application and a web application. Now a days majority of the web applications or lets say website are responsive which means the site will automatically adjust its layout and components sizes with respect to the device screen size. For making a responsive web application you can go through Bootstrap css. As you mentioned earlier you can develop a web application using reactjs. I would suggest you to go through react-bootstrap for making responsive react web application.

Comment: So when a user visits your url from his/her pc or laptop they will see your regular site and if they visit your url from mobile they will see your website in a mobile friendly way.  If you want to make a mobile app like whatsapp or so and you do not know android programming or ios programming but familier with html and css then you should consider using IONIC framework. Basically ionic framework is used to create a mobile applicaiton with the help of html and css,